# Increment sscanf() in a do..while loop and store lines into a struct

Tags: c, file, struct, do-while, scanf

I am given a file as such, [instance10_002](http://pastebin.com/0apvhdMg). I am trying to store the MST data points into a struct that I have made. From my debugging `printf` statements, I can see I have successfully iterated through the file and reached my MST data points.

**Here is my code:**

```
void collect_edges(char filename[31])
{

  int counter = 0, check = 0;
  char c, str[64];
  int index;
  input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (input_file == NULL)
    {
      printf("Input file does not exist\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  while (fgets(str, 64, input_file))
    {
      c = str[0];
      if (c != '#' && c != '\n')
        {
          counter++;
          printf("Check for counter\n");
          if (counter == 2)
            {
              printf("Check Check\n");
              sscanf(str, "%d", &num_pt);
              printf("Check for counter 2\n");
              index = num_pt + 3;
            }


           if (counter == (index))
             {
               printf("Check for counter 13\n");
               printf("Counter is: %d\n", counter);
               do {
                 sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &points[counter-index].parent, &points[counter-index].x, &points[counter-index].distance_to_tree);
                 check++;
                 counter++;
               } while (check <= num_pt - 2);
               break;
             }
         }
    }
  fclose(input_file);

}
```

I have used a `do..while` loop to store all the MST data points into my struct, but when I go to access them, it prints out `0 9 45`, which is the **`0th index`** of my struct and not the right data for all the indices.

**Output by the following method:**

```
collect_edges(argv[inputfile]);
printf("%d\n", points[3].parent);
printf("%d\n", points[3].x);
printf("%d\n", points[3].distance_to_tree);
```

[image: Output]

**Correct output as seen in instance file:**

> 5  8  40

I initially thought my counter was not being incremented in my `do..while` loop but I have included the increment and now it scans the first MST data line and saves it in all the indices of the struct.
Is there a way to increment the `sscanf` function to increment and scan all the other lines of data points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE : I HAVE SOLVED MY PROBLEM!**

Doing more research, I have found it is better to use `fscanf` instead of `sscanf` in my `do..while` loop as `fscanf` utilizes the input filestream. Therefore I dont have to create a loop to further iterate each line, like I had to for `sscanf`.

In changing my code according to `fscanf`, my program yields the correct output.

Also I had to *hard increment* my `counter` to get the indices correct. The following can also be done by leaving the `counter` as the same and *hard decrementing* the `index` instead.

**CHANGED STRUCTURE OF CODE :**

```
if (counter == (index))
  {
    printf("Check for counter 13\n");
    printf("Counter is: %d\n", counter);
    do {
      fscanf(input_file, "%d %d %d", &points[(counter + 1)-index].parent, &points[(counter + 1)-index].x, &points[(counter+1)-index].distance_to_tree);
      check++;
      counter++;
    } while (check <= num_pt - 2);
    break;
```

**Output after executing the following:**

```
collect_edges(argv[inputfile]);
printf("%d\n", points[3].parent);
printf("%d\n", points[3].x);
printf("%d\n", points[3].distance_to_tree);
```

[image: Corrected Output]